# Neo4j configuration files

Tags: macos, neo4j, dmg

I have installed the community trial version of Neo4j for Mac using the dmg installer.

I want to replace the database that comes in default with the installation. 
Where are the configuration files stored in a MAC?

I am specifically looking for config/neo4j-server.properties

Comment: You already know what you're looking for, so give Spotlight a try: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014

Comment: It probably needs an entire path, "path_to_the_neo4_installanation/config/neo4j-server.preprties"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you launch Neo4j App, you can see a "Options..." button. Just in the Options dialog, there's "Database Configuration" and you can find its path or directly edit it using "Edit..." button.